# The meaning of 'rutting' in Tennessee Williams' 'A Streetcar Named Desire'

Tags: vocabulary

Chapter XI begins as follows:

STANLEY: Drew to an inside straight and made it, by God.

PABLO: Maldita sea tu suerte!

STANLEY: Put it in English, greaseball.

PABLO: I am cursing your rutting luck.

---

I wonder what Pablo tried to mean by 'rutting luck'.

Is it damned luck that he said? Then how could rutting be translated as damned?

Comment: When I googled **define +"rutting luck"** I got about 90 results. Apart from this actual ELL question, just about ***every*** result was related to its occurrence in *A Streetcar Named Desire*. So whatever it means, it's not a usage with any currency.

Comment: The play actually does say rutting luck. I just checked. He could mean luck at cards, indirectly, luck at getting the ladies. Steve uses the word too:
That rutting hunkl [meaning having sexual intercourse, like a pig]

Comment: Here is the play online:http://visumbrasov.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/A-Streetcar-Named-Desire-2.pdf

Comment: @Lambie - I don't think it meant luck with the ladies.  I think it was just a vulgar adjective talking about Steve's luck in the card game (making the inside straight).  I think RichF's answer is right on target.

Comment: @aparente001I looked through all the meanings in the OED, and there is nothing but sexual activity that would work. I think it is a euphemism for fucking, here.

Answer (score 3):

I am unfamiliar with the expression "rutting luck".  In context it would seem to be an escalation, with Pablo beginning with "damn luck" in Spanish. Stanley, either rudely or as a familiar friend, demands that he translate it. (I don't know if they are close friends or new acquaintances at the poker table.)  Pablo seems to match the tone of the harsh or jocular word "greaseball" with "rutting luck."  The word "rutting" refers to the act of animals breeding, so "rutting luck" would be a sort of toned-down equivalent to "f**king luck", but still a lot stronger than "damn luck".